# Релиз программы с сторонней библиотекой. C#

Tags: c#, winforms, oxyplot

Подключил стороннюю библиотеку через NuGet(OxyPlot). Как выпустить релиз? Какие файлы нужны для работы программы на других ПК?

Comment: [Публикация приложения  с помощью мастера публикации ClickOnce](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/31kztyey.aspx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для работы на других ПК необходимо выполнить несколько условий:

1. Должен быть установлен .NET Framework, версии не ниже, чем целевая версия, указанная в проекте (см. свойства проекта).
2. Файлы сторонних библиотек, должны находиться рядом с исполняемым файлом, или быть доступными для загрузки в память любым другим способом, например через GAC, как системные сборки, или более сложную структуру папок в проекте. Вовсе не обязательно все валить в одну папку, можно аккуратно разложить по вложенным, тут главное правильно линки прописать в проекте.

При штатной установке через NuGet, сторонняя библиотека линкуется в проект с параметром `Copy local` установленным в `true`. Этот параметр отвечает за необходимость копировать подключенную DLL в выходной каталог приложения. Так можно заставить копироваться и системные сборки, только в этом нет необходимости. Если сомневаетесь, что ваша подключенная DLL попадет в папку приложения, просто проверьте этот параметр в свойствах подключенной сборки.

В принципе для распространения вашего приложения, достаточно переключить конфигурацию проекта в Release и выполнить построение проекта, после чего просто копировать папку /bin/Release на целевую машину или запаковать папку в архив и выложить в сеть. Если нужен инсталятор, то можно воспользоваться технологией ClickOnce (ссылку на документацию привел **@Bulson** в комментарии под вопросом) или любым другим инсталятором, какой больше знаком или просто нравится.

В пользу ClickOnce, можно отнести встроенный механизм автоматического обновления при соответствующей настройке правил публикации. <strike>Однако если у вас большой проект, то не стоит использовать для публикации Visual Studio, т.к. ее встроенная публикация не позволяет использовать частичное обновление и клиентам придется качать все при каждом обновлении.</strike> Ручная публикация приложения ClickOnce тоже возможна, но это уже за рамками данного вопроса.

UPD: У инсталлятора ClickOnce  есть одна нехорошая особенность интерфейса. Несмотря на полную поддержку частичных обновлений, при которой из источника скачиваются только изменившиеся библиотеки, а остальные просто локально копируются в новую папку, по виду и поведению интерфейса можно подумать, что скачивается все приложение целиком, но это не так. Механизм работает как положено и лишний трафик не расходуется, просто интерфейсное решение не слишком удачное, хотя кому как. Данный факт проверял лично, по настоятельной просьбе одного из пользователей.

Answer (score 3):

При подключении библиотеки проблем не должно быть. При запуске в режиме релиза все подключенные библиотеки, автоматически переносятся к расположению программы. Проверьте папку bin/Release. Там Вы увидите свою программу и все подключенные к ней библиотеки. Чтобы использовать её на других компьютерах, просто перенесите содержимое папки на другой компьютер и запустите. В примере я подключил библиотеку AutoMapper и она сама перенеслась к файлу приложения. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Использовать ClickOnce для формирования релиза?

Comment: @NewView вовсе не обязательно. ClickOnce, это один из механизмов публикации релиза, со своими достоинстваими и недостатками. Сам релиз собирается простым билдом в соответствующей конфигурации. После этого можете запаковать сборку в архив и залить на файлообменник например.

Comment: Конечно, никто не спорит, но ClickOnce в принципе удобный инструмент, хоть и глючный. Но берет на себя много всяких 'ручных' забот. Главное правильно оформить его настройки, и жить станет немного легче.. :)

Comment: @NewView а еще отучить студию перепаковывать все смежные файлы при каждой публикации, чтобы таки механизм частичного обновления, который там есть, наконец-то заработал без ручных шаманств